# Calculating average of specific columns from CSV data file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, database, csv

I need help writing a python code that can read data from a csv file using the csv module, cannot use pandas, and then find the average of each row 1-31 in this case. The code should still work if the number of months/rows change. I am continually getting an indexing error and just banging my head against the wall at this point. Most of my experience is in C programming I am older and relatively new to python. Any help is greatly appreciated. Here is the code I have so far.

I am getting an error in the firs for loop - indexerror: list index out of range

I am stumped as to how this is happening, because I have averages set to a blank list. Does this need to be a global variable set to 0 or a list of 0 value elements?

Here is the code I have so far, and an example of the csv data I am working with.

```
with open("RADIOLOGY.csv") as file:
    data = file.readlines()


def compute_averages(data):
    if not data:
        return []

    # num_months = len(data[0:].split()) - 1  # Calculate the number of months
    num_months = len([row.split()[0] for row in data])
    print(num_months)
    print(len(data))
    # averages = [1] * num_months
    averages = []

    for row in data:
        values = row.split()
        for i in range(num_months):
            if i < len(values) - 1:
                averages[i] += float(values[i - 1])

    for i in range(num_months):
        averages[i] /= len(data)

    return averages


def driver():

    if len(data) < 1:
        print("Not enough data to compute averages.")
        return

    # Assuming the first row contains headers and the first column contains observations
    headers = data[0].split()
    observations = [row.split()[0] for row in data]

    averages = compute_averages(data)

    print(f"Number of months: {len(headers) - 1}")
    print("Averages for each observation:")
    for i, observation in enumerate(observations):
        print(f"{observation}: {averages[i]}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    driver()
```

```
1   2317    5327    997 986
2   2605    5617    1085    1105
3   2364    5490    1061    998
4   2975    6236    1129    1164
5   2766    5877    1206    1104
6   2762    6058    1295    908
7   3020    6602    1274    1089
8   2576    5644    1091    1041
9   3329    6643    1396    1130
10  2989    6284    1330    1192
```

Comment: Are the 10 rows of numbers you shared representing your RADIOLOGY.csv file?

Comment: Yes that is what they are representing, the csv file is exactly the same just with 31 rows

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the primary issue with your code is the way you are initializing and updating the `averages` list. Since you start with an empty list `[]`, attempting to access `averages[i]` in your loop will result in an `IndexError` because the list doesn't have any elements in it yet.

```
averages = [0] * num_months  # Initialize averages with zeros
```

To fix this, you should initialize averages with zeros for each month as mentioned above. Assuming file reading and data parsing parts of your code are delivering the desired result, here's a revised version of your code devoid of any file handling and focussing exclusively on the logic:

```py
DATA = """Sr    JAN FEB MAR APR
1   2317    5327    997 986
2   2605    5617    1085    1105
3   2364    5490    1061    998
4   2975    6236    1129    1164
5   2766    5877    1206    1104
6   2762    6058    1295    908
7   3020    6602    1274    1089
8   2576    5644    1091    1041
9   3329    6643    1396    1130
10  2989    6284    1330    1192"""

def compute_averages(data):
    if not data:
        return [], 0

    # Assuming the first row contains headers
    num_months = len(data[0].split()) - 1  # Subtract 1 for the first column
    averages = [0] * num_months  # Initialize averages with zeros

    for row in data[1:]:  # Skip the header row
        values = row.split()
        for i in range(1, len(values)):  # Start from 1 to skip the first column
            averages[i - 1] += float(values[i])

    # Calculate average for each month
    for i in range(num_months):
        averages[i] /= len(data) - 1  # Subtract 1 for the header row

    return averages, num_months

def driver():
    data_lines = DATA.split("\n")  # Replace this line with your file read operation

    # Assuming the first row contains headers
    headers = data_lines[0].split()
    averages, num_months = compute_averages(data_lines)

    print(f"Number of months: {num_months}")
    print("Averages for each observation:")
    for i in range(num_months):
        print(f"{headers[i+1]}: {averages[i]:.2f}")  # i+1 to skip the first header

if __name__ == "__main__":
    driver()
```

Output:

```
Number of months: 4
Averages for each observation:
JAN: 2770.30
FEB: 5977.80
MAR: 1186.40
APR: 1071.70
```

The above code assumes that your CSV file's first row contains headers and the first column in each row is not a part of the average calculation. Also, it assumes there are no missing values in the data rows. If my assumptions are not accurate, you may need to adjust your code accordingly. Additionally, I used the format `{averages[i]:.2f} is used to print the averages with two decimal places.

Comment: Thank you very much, your code works perfectly. I am wondering if maybe I did not understand the question, as the csv file in question has 31 rows for 31 months, I had thought the output has to be 31 individual float values as the averages of each row, not counting the first column 1-31. However, your answer helps me understand much better. Thank you